# GCM mode for AAD in javax.crypto library

Tags: java, cryptography, aes-gcm

have a question about this library and GCM in general.

I understand GCM mode can both encrypt and authenticate data, or merely just authenticate it. With the javax library, if I want to authenticate a message only I can do:

`cipher.updateAAD(AAD)`

My question is, when I compute

`cipher.doFinal(buffer)`

What does buffer become? Is it merely the ciphertext blocks + the GCM auth tag? Or is AAD itself actually included in buffer now?

It's really not clear to me from the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will use the `AES/GCM/NoPadding`, the `doFinal` method produces `ciphertext + tag` when encrypting. The same is expected when decrypting the AES/GCM mode.

If you `updateAAD`, the MAC (tag) is updated, but the AAD itself value is not included (that would even break the purpose of extra AAD).

Comment: If you "just" want authentication I recommend the usage of a **HMAC** and not an authenticated encryption algorithm like GCM.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific reason you are trying to use AAD values?

Not sure your experience level or specific use case, but here is a [blog](https://www.ubiqsecurity.com/blog/understanding-authenticated-encryption-an-explainer) article I wrote about AE if you have any questions.